# PyCrypto: function returned by the decrypt() method

Tags: python, pycrypto, pkcs#1

I want to use RSA in my python web, and I used the pycrypto. But I have some questions in it.
this is my code:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64

random_generator = Random.new().read


def decrypt_rsa(secret):
    with open('/home/ubuntu/project/all/all_test/all_python/util/private_rsa.pem') as file:
        private_key = RSA.importKey(file.read())
        cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
        text = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(secret), random_generator)
        print(str(text))
        return text.decode('utf-8')
```

But when I run a application, I break down with an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/venv/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/flask/app.py", line1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/all_test/all_python/v3/v3_main.py", line 192, in v3_set_article_love
if check_secret(secret):
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/all_test/all_python/v3/v3_main.py", line 18, in check_secret
t = int(secret_util.decrypt_rsa(secret))
File "/home/ubuntu/project/all/all_test/all_python/util/secret_util.py", line14, in decrypt_rsa
return text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

my server os is ubuntu 16.04, with python3.*, and the `secret` is encode by base64, just like `FRw3kfdpHKD4Ms2O3hmaEoD4Gqp5onwF/OUkkp5zSVDsYnJ9Bej8f6kRewoZ/WBZuJIKy8qAUmhi
6qLwK063quA4JKE96Ne6bACIcmkj+boWLoE5TsE3zus4Y8vdwhzsT3Hi9qBjjvmE7IV/LILNQizH
ELp8fdbpGBwwRNlncAQ=`
I would thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer (TL;DR):

The `decrypt()` method is returning your `random_generator` function.

#### Details

If you type

```
help(PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher.decrypt)
```

you can read this from the official documentation:

```
decrypt(self, ct, sentinel) method of 
Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher instance
Decrypt a PKCS#1 v1.5 ciphertext.

[...]    

:Parameters:
[...]
 sentinel : any type
        The object to return to indicate that an error was detected  
        during decryption.
```

As you can read from above, if there is an error during decryption then the `sentinel` object is returned instead of a byte string, then in your code the `decrypt()` method would return the `random_generator` function.

This is why your `text` variable is a function and you cannot treat it as a byte string.

#### Further note

I think there is no need to pass a random generator to `decrypt()` as a sentinel object, because it is just a sentinel object used to detect errors. Please see the [PyCrypto documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) to learn more about this library (but also read [this](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/238) and [this](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html) and consider using [PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/) instead).